# First script game in Java - overloading classes

Tags: java, eclipse, inheritance

```
public abstract class Weapon extends Item {
    Weapon (GameEngine parentEngine)
    {
        super(parentEngine);
    }

    abstract int getMinAttackDamage();
    abstract int getMaxAttackDamage();
    abstract String getAttackVisual(Character attacker, Character attacked, Room attackLocation);
}

So far I have:

Class Axe extends Weapon{
Axe(GameEngine parentGameEngine)[
Super(parentGameEngine);
{
boolean getItemUsable(){
return true;
}
public String get ObjectName();
return "Axe";
}
Public String getItemVisual(){
return "4 foot long handle with a very sharp blade.";
}
```

Here's my question... how/where do I set the minimum/maximum attack damage & character visual? This is my first script game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are thousands of errors in your piece of sample code. Did you try using an IDE. They help you learning much faster as they tell you nicely what is wrong.

```
public class Axe extends Weapon
{

    public Axe(GameEngine parentGameEngine)
    {
        super(parentGameEngine);
    }

    public boolean getItemUsable()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public String getObjectName()
    {
        return "Axe";
    }

    public String getItemVisual()
    {
        return "4 foot long handle with a very sharp blade.";
    }

    public int getMinAttackDamage()
    {
         // fill in
    }

    public int getMaxAttackDamage()
    {
         // fill in
    }

    public String getAttackVisual(Character attacker, Character attacked, Room attackLocation)
    {
         // fill in
    }
}
```

Comment: No I haven't tried using one, do you have a preferred one in mind?  thank you for the feedback.  @ Martijn Corteaux

Comment: I like Eclipse. Second choice would be Netbeans. But that is personal.

Comment: "*There are thousands of errors in your piece of sample code.*": Can you name all of them? :)

Comment: @JoshM: Wrong keyword, visibility, capitalized characters, wrong brackets, constructor doesn't close and open, semi-colon after method signature, overall wrong usage of curly brackets, invalid method signature (by adding spaces) and non-esthetic intendation(which is not an error). Probably forgot some.